# fieldset same line

Tags: html, line, fieldset

I have 2 fieldsets:

```
<fieldset> first fildset </fieldset>

<fieldset> second fieldset </fieldset>
```

how can I place them in same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place them in a div container.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
    height:100px;
    width:600px;
    background-color:gray;       
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    width:400px;
    background-color:red;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="right"><fieldset> first fildset </fieldset></div>
    <div class="left"><fieldset> second fieldset </fieldset></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can set their `display` css property to `inline`:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  fieldset.inline {
    display: inline;
  }
</style>

<fieldset class="inline"> first fildset </fieldset>
<fieldset class="inline"> second fieldset </fieldset>
```

Here's how the result looks: http://jsbin.com/aseyej/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `display:inline;`

Answer (score 1):

feldset is a block level element so normally is appears  in two blocks in page layout so to put them in a line there are many possibilities for instance you can:

a. put `display: inline-block` in style sheet for fieldsets.

b. float one of fieldsets to left or right of other one ie. `float: left`

c. make them absolute or relatively positioned ie. `position: absolute` and set appropriate  top and left

there are also other ways but these three are applicable in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Place them in `table` .as

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <fieldset>
          first fildset
       </fieldset>
     </td>
     <td>
       <fieldset>
          second fieldset 
       </fieldset>
    </td>
</table>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NvC4K/1/) is here

Comment: _No; don't do that._  Tables are for **presenting tabular data**.

Comment: OP didn't say about representation.this is a way to do it but i think w0lf answer is better.

Comment: it is not valid to put block level elements in tabes